# Explicitly disable caching for REST services

Tags: rest, http-caching

I am to apply `Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store` to all responses from out backend REST services. I have two questions about it:

- Is it common to do so? For some reason I was under the impression that it's not necessary, but I have no source to back this claim (yet).
- Is the value I mentioned above really sufficient, or should I set more?

Edit: found this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#cache-prevention. Is says browsers may choose to cache when nothing is explicitly configured, so it means yes, it should be configured if I want to make sure cache is disabled.

Comment: http://www.kennethlange.com/posts/Boost-Your-REST-API-with-HTTP-Caching.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short: yes, caches may cache the response even if no explicit controls are present, you need to explicitly disallow it.

The [HTTP caching specification Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3) lists when the response is forbidden to be cached. It suggests that the response *may* be cached as long as the response code is cacheable. A list of cacheable response codes is in the [HTTP specification section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1):

> Responses with status codes that are defined as cacheable by default
> (e.g., 200, 203, 204, 206, 300, 301, 404, 405, 410, 414, and 501 in
> this specification) can be reused by a cache with heuristic
> expiration unless otherwise indicated by the method definition or
> explicit cache controls...

"Heuristic expiration" is defined as the expiration time assigned when no explicit controls are present. ([HTTP caching specification section 4.2.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2))

Answer (score 4):

I think it's disabled by default. There are mechanisms though to enable caching to enhance performance:

Here's a good explanation with examples how to enable caching:

[Source: [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jax-rs-http-caching)]

> ### Time-based cache headers
>
> In HTTP 1.1 the `Cache-Control` header specifies the resource caching behavior as well as the max age the resource can be cached. As an example, this response would be cached for one day:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cache-Control: private, max-age=86400
> Last-Modified: Thu, 07 Feb 2013 11:56 EST
> ```
>
> Here is a list of all the available `Cache-Control` tokens and their
>   meaning:
>
> - `private` only clients (mostly the browser) and no one else in
>     the chain (like a proxy) should cache this
> - `public` any entity in the chain can cache this
> - `no-cache` should not be cached anyway
> - `no-store` can be cached but should not be stored on disk (most browsers will hold the resources in memory until they will be quit)
> - `no-transform` the resource should not be modified (for example shrink image by proxy)
> - `max-age` how long the resource is valid (measured in seconds)
> - `s-maxage` same like max-age but this value is just for non clients

And here an example with CDI Cache Control annotation:

[Source: [abhirockzz.wordpress.com](https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/02/20/simplifying-jax-rs-caching-with-cdi/)]

> ```
> @Path("/testcache")
> public class RESTfulResource {
>     @Inject
>     @CachControlConfig(maxAge = 20)
>     CacheControl cc;
>
>     @GET
>     @Produces("text/plain")
>     public Response find() {
>         return Response.ok(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).cacheControl(cc).build();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, I will read the links. Just one thing: 'I think' is not really a good answer.

Comment: No problem. Mark it accordingly :)