# How to disable REST API caching

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, caching, axios

I have a stat tracker web app that built with vue.js for frontend and deployed on vercel. Also i have backend built with express.js and deployed on heroku. Whenever i search user stats it caches the result.
How to disable that caching result?

Frontend:

```
axios.defaults.headers = {
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Expires': '0',
};
```

Backend:

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(nocache()) //npm library
app.set('etag',false)
app.disable('view cache')
```

Comment: also i noticed that, its only being cached on vercel not on localhost.

Answer (score 1):

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129932/explicitly-disable-caching-for-rest-services[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129932/explicitly-disable-caching-for-rest-services%5B1%5D) answers this question in some way. You can implement a middleware that sets `Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store` to all headers we want to disable caching on.

Comment: that nocache() library already adds them.